# Fetching messages from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to make a "forum" in real time. For this i used WebSockets/socket.io , node.js, javascript and MySQL.

I want the messages to stay and be saved even when someone reloads the site or goes into it again.

The code actually does work in sending messages in real time. And it saves the messages to my MySQL database.

However, when I reload the site, all the messages disappear.

I need it so that it fetches all the messages in the database and displays them even when you load the page

heres the back-end code

```
const http = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: { origin: "*" }
});

const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'thehostishere',
  user: 'myuserishere',
  password: 'mypassishere',
  database: 'messages',
  port: 3306
});

connection.connect((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to the database');
  }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  // Fetch existing messages from the database
  connection.query('SELECT `text` FROM messages', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving messages:', error);
    } else {
      console.log('Retrieved messages from the database');
      // Extract the text values from the result rows
      const messages = results.map((row) => row.text);
      // Emit the existing messages to the connected user
      socket.emit('existingMessages', messages);
    }
  });

  socket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);

    // Save the message to the database
    connection.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', { text: message }, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error saving message:', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Message saved to database');
      }
    });

    io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said ${message}`);
  });
});

http.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on http://localhost:8080'));

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  connection.end();
  process.exit();
});
```

and the front-end code

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

socket.on('message', text => {
  const el = document.createElement('li');
  el.innerHTML = text;
  document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(el);
});

socket.on('existingMessages', messages => {
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the existing messages first
  messages.forEach(message => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = message;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
});

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  const text = document.querySelector('input').value;
  socket.emit('message', text);
};
```

the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        
    </ul>

    <input placeholder="message">
    <button>Send</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The MySQL database name is "messages" and all the messages are saved into a column called "text"

I tried fixing the code but it didn't work and when I refresh the site the messages keep on going away and they don't stay

Comment: You may want to consider using [Connection state recovery](https://socket.io/docs/v4/connection-state-recovery). This has a configurable `maxDisconnectionDuration` property which will allow you to recover the clients state if someone closes their browser or loses connection and is a very common implementation when using Socket.IO

Comment: bro thank you so much ive been trying to fix this for hours it just worked

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project.